# Android Studio does not show sourcefiles any more

Tags: android

Android Studio 1.0 and 1.1, running on Windows 8.1 and 10:
In the project tree, the Java node is visible, however it cannot be opened any more by clicking it. The sorucefiles cannot be displayed or reached from the project tree any more.
The sourcefiles still exists in an intermediate... folder and can only be displayed by Ctrl-H (show recent).
How do I repair/reset/... Android Studio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`File` | `Invalidate Caches / Restart...` | `Invalidate and Restart`

If this doesn't help, and if a new Android Studio project behaves properly, then there is probably something in your project that's causing the unwanted behavior. To start clean, try importing your source files as a new project.

Comment: it does not work with my projects. The indexing progress bar appears at the bottom, however the java node cannot be opened.

Comment: Does Android Studio exhibit the same behavior if you try creating a new project?  If not, then there is probably something in your project that's causing the behavior; try importing the source files as a new project and see if that helps.  Either way, the tools team would probably appreciate it if you found and starred an existing bug that relates to your issue, or filed a new one if it hasn't been filed already:  http://b.android.com/

Comment: Thank you very much: Importing instead of opening repairs the project.